# Why the below pattern matching is giving True for the String "ababx300000055773908"

Tags: java, regex

Firstly sorry for the primitive question, I am wondering how the below method is returning true

```
  Pattern.compile("([0-9]{15})").asPredicate().test("ababx300000055773908")
```

Please let me know, if i am missing something here.

Comment: Your regular expression is not anchored to the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate()): "Creates a predicate that tests if this pattern is **found** in a given input string." - the pattern represents a sequence of 15 digits (`0`-`9`) and the string contains 15 digits (`300000055773908`), so it is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the start and the end of the String to match.
your pattern is matching the 15 times numeric in the whole string without considering the location of the pattern.
use regex ^[0-9]{15}$

```
Pattern.compile("(^[0-9]{15}$)").asPredicate().test("ababx300000055773908");
```

Comment: Got it..Thanks Somnath